# Google Maps API: data layer rendering complete event

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geojson

I'm using Google Maps API to display my Polygon data on map. The data is present is in geoJson format and the file size is 2Mb. This is how I'm adding data to layer

```
var parcelLayer = new google.maps.Data();
parcelLayer.addGeoJson(geoJsonObject);
```

and everything is working fine.

But the issue I'm facing is; the data file size is big enough i.e approx 2Mb, it takes 5-10 seconds to render on map so I need to add a loader for the time when data is rendering on the map.

I'm unable to find such an event which trigger after the map data finish rendering or any trick which can be helpful in this case. I've searched on Google alot and checked relevant links of this website as well but no luck

**Edited**

I've tried `addfeature` event like below

```
            count=0;
            parcelLayer.addListener('addfeature', function() {
                count+=1;
                if (count==geoJsonObject.features.length){
                    console.log('all rendered');
                }
            });
```

But the `console` responds far before the layer finish rendering.

Comment: Have you tried the [addfeature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data) event?  You might need a count of the features in the GeoJSON to know when the last one is added.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried addfeature event. But the response of addfeature for all features comes up and the layer is yet rendering. Example of that is added in question

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem and was able to follow @AniV's advice successfully.

But I wanted to throw in an additional detail which had been the source of my confusion. The Google Maps API allows you to load GeoJSON data in one of two ways:

1) `loadGeoJson`: This takes a URL path as an argument and pulls in JSON via a GET request to that URL. The JSON response by the server, assuming it follows correct GeoJSON format, will be added to the map.

2) `addGeoJson`: This is what you used above. It takes the JSON itself as the argument and adds it to the map.

Here's where I got tripped up: I recently switched from using `loadGeoJson` to using `addGeoJson` and, as it turns out, the event listener `addfeature` does **not** work in the same way for both methods.

For `loadGeoJson`, it seems to me that all the features returned by the server get added at once, such that the event listener `addfeature` fires after **all* markers have been added. But for `addGeoJson`, the features seem to be added one at a time, such that the `addfeature` listener fires before all the markers are added (or perhaps not at all? I couldn't tell which was the case) and thus the code block is not executed.

To get around this, I have successfully used @AniV's answer. But I wanted to provide this additional information in case anyone switching from `loadGeoJson` to `addGeoJson` runs into the same problem I did.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    // you can put your layer code for data is present is in geoJson      format here
});
```

"Idle" event is triggered when the map is fully loaded that means it is idle.

Comment: You mean I need to initiate the layer inside the above mentioned function?

Comment: Yes if the whole layer has the functions that you want to expose only when the map finishes loading!!

Comment: The map is still rendering when this fires.